# Installing fbsimctl in Travis

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, travis-ci, detox

I'm working on a new build travis which integrates e2e tests on iOS but I'm having problems installing `fbsimctl`. I want to use `detox`, and this is one of the prerequisites to use it.

This is the log when trying to install it:

```
$ brew install fbsimctl --HEAD
==> Installing fbsimctl from facebook/fb
==> Installing dependencies for facebook/fb/fbsimctl: carthage
==> Installing facebook/fb/fbsimctl dependency: carthage
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/carthage-0.26.2.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring carthage-0.26.2.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
zsh completions have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/carthage/0.26.2: 75 files, 25.9MB
==> Installing facebook/fb/fbsimctl --HEAD
==> Cloning https://github.com/facebook/FBSimulatorControl.git
Cloning into '/Users/travis/Library/Caches/Homebrew/fbsimctl--git'...
remote: Counting objects: 1136, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (993/993), done.
remote: Total 1136 (delta 278), reused 372 (delta 123), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (1136/1136), 1.19 MiB | 794.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (278/278), done.
Checking out files: 100% (1004/1004), done.
==> Checking out branch master
==> ./build.sh fbsimctl build /usr/local/Cellar/fbsimctl/HEAD-e6f8e6b
Last 15 lines from /Users/travis/Library/Logs/Homebrew/fbsimctl/01.build.sh:
  dispatch_source_set_timer(dispatchSource, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, timeInterval), timeInterval, 0);
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
CompileC build/Build/Intermediates/FBSimulatorControl.build/Debug/FBControlCore.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FBTaskConfiguration.o FBControlCore/Tasks/FBTaskConfiguration.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws/build/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws/build/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Xclang -fmodule-implementation-of -Xclang FBControlCore -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Werror -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wunused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wunknown-pragmas -Wshadow -Wfour-char-constants -Wconversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wsign-compare -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wnewline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -g -Wsign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -iquote /tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws/build/Build/Intermediates/FBSimulatorControl.build/Debug/FBControlCore.build/FBControlCore-generated-files.hmap -I/tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws/build/Build/Intermediates/FBSimulatorControl.build/Debug/FBControlCore.build/FBControlCore-own-target-headers.hmap -I/tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws/build/Build/Intermediates/FBSimulatorControl.build/Debug/FBControlCore.build/FBControlCore-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws/build/Build/Intermediates/FBSimulatorControl.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws/build/Build/Intermediates/FBSimulatorControl.build/Debug/FBControlCore.build/FBControlCore-project-headers.hmap -I/tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws/build/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws/PrivateHeaders -I/tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws/build/Build/Intermediates/FBSimulatorControl.build/Debug/FBControlCore.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws/build/Build/Intermediates/FBSimulatorControl.build/Debug/FBControlCore.build/DerivedSources -F/tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws/build/Build/Products/Debug -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../PlugIns -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../OtherFrameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../SharedFrameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks -F/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws/build/Build/Intermediates/FBSimulatorControl.build/Debug/FBControlCore.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FBTaskConfiguration.d --serialize-diagnostics /tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws/build/Build/Intermediates/FBSimulatorControl.build/Debug/FBControlCore.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FBTaskConfiguration.dia -c /tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws/FBControlCore/Tasks/FBTaskConfiguration.m -o /tmp/fbsimctl-20171128-6651-1lg5ws/build/Build/Intermediates/FBSimulatorControl.build/Debug/FBControlCore.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FBTaskConfiguration.o
** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/Build/Intermediates/FBSimulatorControl.build/Debug/FBControlCore.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FBDispatchSourceNotifier.o FBControlCore/Utility/FBDispatchSourceNotifier.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
https://github.com/facebook/homebrew-fb/issues
The command "brew install fbsimctl --HEAD" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

The cache permissions I've granted are these:

```
cache:
  yarn: true
  directories:
    - node_modules
    - $HOME/Library/Caches/Homebrew
    - $HOME/Library/Caches
    - $HOME/Library/Caches/carthage
    - /usr/local/Cellar/fbsimctl
    - /usr/local/Cellar
```

But I don't know what else do I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fbsimctl is no longer a dependency of Detox since we had lots of trouble with it, mainly because it is not always stable and there's no way of getting a stable version.

If you have issues with Fbsimctl, open an issue in fbsimctl's GitHub page.

Unrelated to Detox, if you still want to install Fbsimctl, you can install the latest stable version 0.4.0 (Apr 2017) by `brew install fbsimctl@0.4.0`